# How to insert a number+1, +2 next to the position of that number in the list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I want to be able to insert numbers +1 , +2 based off the number in the list, directly next to that number it is based off of.

Example:

```
# existing list
list1 = [1,10,100]

#wanted output: 
[1,2,3, 10,11,12, 100,101,102]

#I spaced out the output list for ease of reading/understanding what it is I want to do.
```

I would also like to be able to add up to +7 and more, so if it is possible please help make it efficient in this way.

Comment: `[number + offset for number in list1 for offset in range(3)]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple nested comprehension:

```
list1 = [1, 10, 100]
n = 3  # or 7 or whatever


list2 = [x for y in list1 for x in range(y, y+n)]
# [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 100, 101, 102]
```

Comment: Clever.  If it want to be operated on the `same` list` - then could do this: `list1[:] = [x for y .....]`  Then no extra new copy need to be created.

Comment: Yup, exactly. Slice assignment would be the way to go there.

Comment: @DanielHao Even though, I would recommend then on principal reasons to use a generator expression: `list1[:] = (x for y ...)` to avoid a spurious in memory list.

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed

Answer (score 1):

You can use this. It creates a list of item, item+1, item+2 and then flattens it before returning -

```
list1 = [1, 10, 100]
[j for i in list1 for j in [i,i+1,i+2]]
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 100, 101, 102]
```

Comment: Thank you, the flattening part is handy for me elsewhere in my code :)

Comment: Your code is now perfect for something else I am working on, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad to help. Do mark the answer if it helped you and do upvote it if it’s well written to your liking. This encourages me to help solve your future questions :)